# Is there common practice to find required header files of libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, c, header, header-files

I am fairly new to C++ and this might sound like a very dumb question, but is there any resource or common practice to find the headers that need to be included when using C/C++ libraries?

For example: I am currently doing a project using the OpenSSL library.
How do I find out which headers I need to include for the sample codes on this page:

- https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Key_and_Parameter_Generation

I had this issue many times and I am almost always struggling to find the right header files to include if the documentation doesn't provide a full working example.

Am I missing smoething when it comes to finding the required header files or is this lack of documentation the norm for examples?

Comment: Are you asking for C or C++?

Comment: For C++, the list of standard headers is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header). Search for whatever feature you aren't sure about on that site and it will tell you which header you need. If you need to find out about non-standard headers, like 3rd party libraries, you have to hope that library's documentation is up to par.

Comment: For C, the man page for each function has the required header(s) at the top of the synopsis section.

Comment: One simple way is to grep through the includes directory for the OpenSSL function call you are making.  Which includes directory OpenSSL is installed in, depends on your distribution, and where it installs OpenSSL.  If this is a Linux system, start with /usr/include

Comment: You don't usually have this problem because you typically learn of the header before you know all of its functionality. Or you read through the headers to see the interface.

Comment: Yet another option is to use a good IDE like CLion: if you have a cmake configuration to let it know which library include directories to scan, it'll find all the available functions and if you call a function that the translation unit hasn't included, it'll be highlighted with a pop-up suggestion for the header to include for it - can just hit Alt-Enter or something similar to have it insert the #include atop the file and let you keep working.  CLion's not free, but it's absolutely worth it if you spend more than a couple hours a week coding.

Comment: @Mansoor I disagree, most of the times you will find some documentation or pages that promise certain functionality without mentioning the actual header files.

Comment: (1) Try to compile the code. (2) When the compiler complains about undeclared things, look them up in documentation for your system (such as “man” pages for Unix). The documentation will say what header is needed. (3) Insert `#include` for the specified header(s).

Comment: @j.Doe I think the most common page is cppreference.com. The header is the first thing it mentions.

Comment: okay, think it's about right revision of a library project in Version Control System. If it exists.

Comment: @Mansoor cppreference.com is certainly not the most common page people obtain code samples from. Especially not if using third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that you were hoping to find something like a fancy database or any secret documentation to get the header.

Like for the `Qt framework` in the `Qt Creator` would be positioning the cursor on a written class in the code and just pressing `alt` + `enter` is adding the necessary header on top of the code.

Sadly that functionality is just for `Qt` not for `c/c++` implemented.

The correct answer to your question might be as simple and maybe basic as so and it is also the fastest way I found and probably most people use:

- ***A search engine of your choice***(*Google, DuckDuckgo, Startpage.com ...)*
- ***library command*** *(f.e. `EVP_PKEY`)*
- ***Programming language name*** *(f.e. `c++`, `Qt`, ...)*

*Proof of concept f.e. for [startpage.com](http://startpage.com):*
[image: Search engine result]

Maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header is an alternative - I just never found stuff real quick there.

---

The second best option I found and use regularly to find in addition to the header even good sample codes/examples is a program called [Recoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoll) *(For Linux, Mac and Windows - or a similar desktop search engine)*

> Recoll is based on the very capable Xapian search engine library, for
> which it provides a powerful text extraction layer and a complete, yet
> easy to use, Qt graphical interface.
> (https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/)

**It works like that:**

- I put a selection of the best 50 books to a special topic in a folder *(f.e. `c++`, `c`, `qt` - just stay really specific)* and let recoll crawl the folder.
- Now use keywords like `EVP_PKEY` to find every topic in all of your most loved and respected pdf `c++` books in nano- to milliseconds - depending on how much money you spend on your pdf library. (Sure, you have to get/buy them first)

*(But its a freaking fast tool and even prioritized due to the Xapian search engine library)*